# What this formula for product of two complex vectors is?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, vector-analysis

I read in one russian book about complex vectors. There was formula for product of two complex vectors. I was confused because I didn't find what this formula is.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{z}_{1} \boldsymbol{z}_2 
&= (\boldsymbol{a}_1 + i\boldsymbol{b}_1) (\boldsymbol{a}_2 + i\boldsymbol{b}_2) \\
&= \bigl[ (\boldsymbol{a}_1, \boldsymbol{a}_2) - (\boldsymbol{b}_1, \boldsymbol{b}_2) \bigr] 
+ i \bigl[ (\boldsymbol{a}_1, \boldsymbol{b}_2) + (\boldsymbol{b}_1, \boldsymbol{a}_2) \bigr]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ are vectors not numbers,
$(\boldsymbol{a}_1, \boldsymbol{a}_2)$ and so on is scalar product of two vectors.

What this formula for product of two complex vectors is?

Comment: you could call it the complexification of the real inner product. note that it will not become an inner product on the complexified space because it's not conjugate linear in one argument

Comment: This is just the multiplication of complex numbers using that $i^2=-1$. So $(a+bi)(x+yi)=a(x+yi)+bi(x+yi)=ax+ayi+bxi+byi^2=(ax-by)+(ay+bx)i$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField No. $a$ and $b$ are vectors not numbers.

Comment: This is not a product in the usual meaning. The product of two vectors is a (complex) scalar. The scalar product is an orthogonal — not hermitian — inner product, we assume.

Comment: @Mike_bb what book are you getting this from? How do they define $(a_1,a_2)$ for vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$? That alone is weird.

Comment: @CyclotomicField They define only properties for scalar product for vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$ but they don't define $(a_1,a_2)$

Comment: @Mike_bb if it's not defined then it's impossible to know what they mean. It's a core part of the expression you're given.  Maybe it was a copy/paste error?

Comment: @CyclotomicField See page 42 (38) https://rsmu.ru/fileadmin/templates/DOC/Faculties/PF/Phys-mat/akimov_kompl_chisla.pdf

Comment: @Mike_bb unfortunately the link isn't working for me. I tried googling the document itself but it only provides the same link.

Comment: The scalar product of two vectors is a bilinear product that is part of the given data of any real inner product space. So it does not require a definition. But if you like, you can choose a basis where the definition is $(a_1,a_2)=(a_1)_x(a_2)_x+(a_1)_y(a_2)_y.$ Here we see the author extending it to a bilinear product on the complexification.